# SQL with calculation based on multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a simple DB with the following two tables.

There is a one-to-many relationship between the `id` field in the sessions table
and the `session_id` field in the candidates table.

I'd like a query that will `SELECT * FROM SESSIONS`.

```
SESSIONS (TABLE)

|| id || title || max_candidates || description ||
|| 01 || fish  || 05             || some string ||
|| 02 || birds || 10             || some string ||

CANDIDATES (TABLE)

|| session_id || user_id ||
|| 01         || user01  ||
|| 02         || user12  ||
|| 02         || user03  ||
|| 02         || user05  ||
```

However, in addition to returning the information from the sessions table,
I'd also like it to return a *calculated column* named `avaliable_spaces`.

I'd like to have this column return the number of avalaible spaces for a particular
session based on (no of times `session_id` occurs in `CANDIDATES`) - (`max_candidates`)

In the above example it would return (obviously minus the column `headders`);

```
|| id || title || max_candidates || description || avaliable_spaces ||

|| 01 || fish  || 05             || some string ||04                ||
|| 02 || birds || 10             || some string ||07                ||
```

Does this make sense? And if so, is it even possible!? (as you can probably guess)
I'm an SQL noob and this is well beyond me!

Comment: Ummm is this a homework problem?

Comment: Judging by the "Timbob" it seems to be.

Comment: Hi, no - its an 'I have extremely limited experience of SQL problem'. Many thanks for your input, I'll give it a whirl on Monday.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT S.id,
       S.title,
       S.max_candidates,
       S.description,
       S.max_candidates - COUNT(c.user_id) as available_spaces
FROM   SESSIONS S
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CANDIDATES C
         ON C.session_id = s.id
GROUP  BY S.id,
          S.title,
          S.max_candidates,
          S.description
```

Comment: no need for the `OUTER`, left joins are inherently outer joins.

Comment: @vol7ron No reason not to include it either. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: There's plenty of reason: larger file size, more difficult to interpret, it makes the code convoluted, it makes your code ugly when formatting (which it seems you don't do anyhow), it's just not necessary.

Comment: @vol7ron - lol it doesn't make it any more difficult to interpret or convoluted, ugliness is clearly subjective and your argument that the optional `OUTER` keyword should not be used due to the effect on file size is frankly laughable. Do you give all your tables and columns one character names for similar reasons? You should be pleased at the lack of formatting anyway. White space takes up valuable bytes :-)

Comment: @Martin: the fact that you consider my comment to apply to only one join statement for one query in one project is "laughable".  The fact that you don't consider nested joins, or complicated recursive statements shows your experience.  Yes, extra keywords do make it harder to read, your argument is without base.  White space doesn't take up any extra bytes, whereas if I chose to use `OUTER` every place there was a full, left, or right join, it would add up if you have many projects as I do.  And, unfortunately, space conservation is still important when you buy it at contracted prices.

Comment: @Whomever is subtracting points: I'm not saying that his solution is worth a `-1` as I do agree that the formatting and legibility is subjective, however there have been studies to show that given two, equal, common phrases; it's easier to interpret the one with fewer words.

Comment: @vol7ron - I'd imagine one of the downvotes is JonH's he was active today and I've noticed before has some pathological objection to long `GROUP BY` lists (preferring the technique in @gbn's answer). You're never going to convince me to care about whether `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` is used I'm afraid!

Comment: It takes more vertical space, but I made an answer that showed another formatting of your code (w/o the `OUTER`).  Of course, it's still a matter of subjection and the formatting rules would also depend on how many nested joins, how many fields are selected, basically other external factors not in the listed solutions.

Comment: vol7ron - Yes I noticed that and chucked my answer through an online code formatter http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: @Martin: very beautiful +1, sometimes I indent the JOIN under the previous table, thought my rule goes, to keep it aligned with the `FROM` statement.  I've also adopted someone else's standard of putting commas in front.  I originally didn't like that, but it's helped in debugging.  Of course, as you've said, this is all a matter of taste.  It's better to be consistent in this case. -- I'm still for no `OUTER`, though :)

Comment: I think gbn's solution would be faster, having less group conditions, though.

Comment: @vol7ron - I'd expect any half decent query optimiser to realise that `id` is the primary key and only bother using that as the `group by` column. Certainly that is the case in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    S.*, S.max_candidates - C.Filled AS avaliable_spaces
FROM
    SESSIONS S
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT session_id, COUNT(*) AS Filled FROM CANDIDATES GROUP BY session_id
    ) C ON S.ID = C.session_id
```